# Flutter bitbucket pipeline script

Tags: flutter, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to create a pipeline for building Flutter (iOS/android) on Bitbucket. I couldn't find any for the iOS part.
For the android I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504492/flutter-pipeline-with-bitbucket)

Is there any for iOS which can build and deploy to TestFlight?

Comment: for ios you need a real mac device to build it. There is a beta for it: https://bitbucket.org/blog/beta-macos-runners-bitbucket

Comment: Alright, thanks! I've made this with codemagic but I thought I could also do it with bitbucket. Now that codemagic works I can delete my macOS docker